# how to create multiple list from dataframe in spark?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to create multiple list from dataframe in spark.
In my case, I want to order mongodb documents with grouping specific key.  and create multiple list which is grouped on the basis of one key of schema
please help me

```
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
MongoSpark.load[SparkSQL.Character](sparkSession).printSchema()
val characters = MongoSpark.load[SparkSQL.Character](sparkSession)
characters.createOrReplaceTempView("characters")
val sqlstmt = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE site = 'website'")
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
val columns = sqlstmt.columns.map(col)

task1
  .groupBy(key)
  .agg(collect_list(struct(columns: _*)).as("data"))
```

Don't forget to import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```